# paket - how to install packages to project's local folder

Tags: f#, paket

Paket - how to install packages to project's local folder ?

`paket install` always place nugets to some global directory like`C:/Users/xxx/.nuget/packages/fsharp.data/3.3.3/lib/net45/FSharp.Data.dll`

Answer (score 4):

As per [the paket documentation](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/dependencies-file.html#Disable-packages-folder) adding `storage: packages` to your `paket.dependencies` file should do it.